# Akka Camel websocket client producer

Tags: java, apache-camel, akka

I am trying to communicate with a websocket server using Apache Camel AHC-Websocket Component with Akka Camel in Java. In this case, websocket endpoint is goint to be a well known websocket public [service](https://www.websocket.org/echo.html).

Using:

- JDK **8.x**
- Akka Java API with Akka Camel, Akka Actor and Akka SLF4J **2.3.9**
- Apache Camel with AHC WS Component **2.14.1**

I followed Akka Camel tutorial for Java located over [here](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.1.4/java/camel.html).

Short description: Every response received by `UntypedProducerActor` when I make a request returns `CamelMessage` with `body` field as `null`. But when I make request via `ProducerTemplate` I receive correct response.

Long description: I am getting strange behaviour from Akka Camel when I make a request and expect a response from the websocket endpoint. When I make a request to the endpoint via defined ActorRef, for example like so:

```
ActorRef wsProducer = getContext().actorOf(SimpleProducer.props("ahc-ws:echo.websocket.org"));

final Timeout timeout = new Timeout(3, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
final Future<Object> future = Patterns.ask(wsProducer, "Please, respond!", timeout);
final Object result = Await.result(future, timeout.duration());
```

I clearly see in the logs that Apache Camel websocket endpoint received a response:

`DEBUG o.a.c.component.ahc.ws.WsEndpoint    - received message --> Please, respond!`

But the `result` object will be a `CamelMessage` with `body` field always set to `null`. The same `CamelMessage` present in `public Object onTransformResponse(Object message)` method of my `SimpleProducer`.

However, when I make request via `ProducerTemplate` like this:

```
final Camel camel = CamelExtension.get(getContext().system());
final CamelContext context = camel.context();
final ProducerTemplate template = camel.template();

Object result = template.requestBody("ahc-ws:echo.websocket.org", "Alpha is there!");
```

It works and result will contain correct response body: `"Alpha is there!"`.

My `SimpleProducer` is pretty much the same as in tutorial:

```
public class SimpleProducer extends UntypedProducerActor {
    private final LoggingAdapter LOG = Logging.getLogger(getContext().system(), this);

    private final String mEndpointUri;

    public SimpleProducer(final String serverUrl) {
        mEndpointUri = serverUrl;
    }

    @Override
    public String getEndpointUri() {
        return mEndpointUri;
    }

    @Override
    public Object onTransformResponse(Object message) {
        return super.onTransformOutgoingMessage(message);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isOneway() {
        return false;
    }

    public static Props props(final String endpointUri) {
        return Props.create(new Creator<SimpleProducer>() {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            public SimpleProducer create() throws Exception {
                return new SimpleProducer(endpointUri);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Maybe somebody had the same issue and can help me out?

Comment: Hi George. Did you find a solution to your problem? I ran into a similar situation and can't find the reason. Would appreciate if you could find a minute to share your experience. Many thanks!

Comment: Hi Sergio. Unfortunately, not. However, akka-http will include websocket implementation at some point...